# Chrome/HTML5: Input type number not respecting max attribute?

Tags: forms, html, google-chrome

I have the following markup:

```
<input type="number" max="99" />
```

In Google Chrome (and possibly other webkit browsers), this will restrict the spinner's up arrow from going over 99, but it **does not** prevent the user from typing a number higher than 99.  Even onblur, the invalid value is not removed/replaced or even a warning given that the value is invalid.

Am I misinterpreting how it's supposed to work, or is this a bug?  I am using the latest version of Chrome (19 at the time of writing).

**Edit:**

To clarify, I want to know why a number greater than the specified max is allowed to be input in the first place.  I realize that it gives a tooltip on form submission telling you that it's invalid, but it seems like inconsistent behavior that the spinner will not allow you to go above the max, yet you can simply type a number above the max at any time to circumvent it.

If this is desired behavior for some reason, why is that?  And is there a better option to enforcing the input range without resorting to JS?

Comment: Works fine for me, I get the error message "Value must be less than or equal to 99.". Can we see your actual code please?

Comment: Chrome and Opera all throw a warning when I try to submit a form that has a number outside the range: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Uv3EA/

Comment: Why would this only show on form submission?  And more importantly, why is it allowed in the first place?  It restricts the spinner so you can't use that to input a higher value - why not manual input as well?  And I can't use maxlength, or pattern to restrict it either, as these aren't applicable to number type inputs.  I'm stuck writing a JS kludge...

Comment: In general, restricting keyboard input for arbitrary range is impossible. Suppose that <input type=number min=10 max=99>, and a browser can't reject '1' though it is out of the range.

Comment: @int32_t:  The browser could reject "1".  It would just have to do so onblur, just like it does if you type "a" instead.  If it can tell that a value is a valid number, then I see no reason it couldn't also enforce the range...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does work but you only see an error message (tooltip) if you put a submit button and a  form into your code:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
  <input type="number" max="99" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TAftq/)
    ​

Comment: Thank you, but that only shows an error message.  I'm more concerned with why it's allowing a value to be input that is greater than the max in the first place.  The spinner control doesn't let you go above the max, so why does it let you type a number greater?  Seems like an oversight or bug to me.

Comment: Apparently the powers that be disagree with my classifying this as a bug.

Comment: This is totally a bug, please restate their oversight to them :c

Answer (score 2):

It's an old question, but I didn't find any relevant answers for this question anywhere.
this behaviour is still around in chrome (version 61).

I have found a little trick that can be used in some situation.
it's relevant for those who use data-binding libraries like `aurelia`, `angular` etc.. I tested only on aurelia - but that should work also for others.

the trick relies on the fact that input of type `range` enforce the `min`/`max` constraints.

we simply create another input (of type `range`) that is bounded to the same value as the regular input, and we hide it via `css`.

when the user inputs something that is greater than the `max` value, it will snap back to the `max` value.

here's a demo in aurelia: https://gist.run/?id=86fc278d3837718be4691acd5625aaad